# Detect OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, hook

For a very peculiar requirement of a DLP software, I'm trying to detect OpenFileDialogs and cancel the file selection action, after capturing the selected file.

How am I trying to do this?

I put a global hook on the mouse and keyboard. I detect all actions that the user can perform to select a file in the OpenFileDialog window.

What I could not do until now is to detect if the window is an OpenFileDialog by hwnd.

Why am I trying this way?

I am a high level programmer and tried initially with windows hooks, without success. I tried with easyhook and deviare2. There seems to be no simpler way to put a global hook in a COM (IFileDialog) component call.

Is there any way to detect if a window is the default Windows OpenFileDialog window by hwnd?

```
public bool IsOpenFileDialog(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    return ?
}
```

Comment: Which operating systems would you like this to work on?

Comment: You can check, say, class name `GetClassName`, enumerate controls etc. however, you can't be totally sure: there's a possibility that adversary's created the window with the same class name, controls, width and height etc.

Comment: Hi @DavidHeffernan, Just Windows, XP, 7, 8, 10, and popular Server Versions.

Comment: So find the class name on each of those operating systems, and compare against that. But note that some other program may create a window class with the same name, and that future versions of windows might change things. Why would you ever want to know that information anyway?

Comment: @David Hefferman, I have a very peculiar requirement for DLP software. Tks for reply.

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko, Tks for reply. I will do it

Comment: People voting down without even leaving a comment... Two favorites

Comment: @ViniciusGonçalves what is the exact requirement? This sounds like a possible [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).

Comment: Great @RemyLebeau, now I understood perfectly. I'll edit the question. Tks very much.

Comment: Please note that posters here are not just male in gender. Some of our female helpers have expressed the opinion that every time they see references to a "gentlemen" audience, they feel excluded. Therefore, please try to avoid using this sort of address, or indeed any gendered language. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @halfer. I'll pay attention on next posts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a *partial solution* (an adversary can mimic such a dialog), I suggest checking if the window a *standard dialog* and if it is, does it have *"Save"* in the caption (you can well put a *better ctriterium* here):

First, let's check `class`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633574(v=vs.85).aspx

```
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

 ... 

 [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
  private static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, 
    StringBuilder lpClassName, 
    int nMaxCount);

  private static String WndClassName(IntPtr handle) {
    int length = 1024;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);

    GetClassName(handle, sb, length);

    return sb.ToString();
  }

  public static bool IsDialogClassName(IntPtr handle) {
    // Standard windows dialogs like OpenFileDialog, SaveFileDialog have #32770 class name 
    return "#32770".Equals(WndClassName(handle));
  }
```

However, it's too wide criterium: both `Save File Dialog` and `Open File Dialog` pass it. Let's check window's caption:

```
  [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
   private static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

  [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
   static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, 
     StringBuilder text, 
     int length);

   private static String WindowText(IntPtr handle) {
     int length = GetWindowTextLength(handle);

     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length + 1);

     GetWindowText(handle, sb, length + 1);

     return sb.ToString();
   }

   public static bool IsSaveCaption(IntPtr handle) {
     //TODO: put a better check for dialog's caption here
     return WindowText(handle).IndexOf("Save", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
   }
```

Finally:

```
  public bool IsOpenFileDialog(IntPtr hwnd) {
    return IsDialogClassName(hwnd) && 
           !IsSaveCaption(hwnd);
  }
```

Sure you may want some other criteria, but I hope these two will be enough

Comment: thank you so much @Dmitry! I'm going to follow this sample to provide the solution. I'll add some more filters, like checking the dialog child control classes, maybe some relative positioning like top navigation bar < treeview top